# How to open Google Maps click on embed maps in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm trying to open Google Maps app when I click on embed google maps sdk in Xcode. Please help me in order to find the solution?

Comment: you want to open iOS GoogleMap in iPhone from your application right?

Comment: Just open or you want path from source to destination place?

Comment: mean below answer is not work for you? You want path right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add one key in .plist file "LSApplicationQueriesSchemes" and mention one item "comgooglemaps" in that.

Then try this code.

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"comgooglemaps:"]]) {
    NSURL *directionsURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"comgooglemaps://"];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:directionsURL];
}
else{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL
                                                URLWithString:@"https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/google-maps/id585027354?mt=8"]];
}
```